# How to set the directory where django saves the pdf's created through reportlab?

Tags: python, django, pdf, canvas

## I am creating a pdf through django view,dynamically using user input using the ReportLab API. Following is the code I implemented:

```
 from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

 p = canvas.Canvas(name)             #create pdf object
 p.drawString(100, 100, b)           #variable b being the user input
 p.showPage()
 p.save()
```

the pdf is saved in the project folder itself. how do i set the desired path for the pdf's to be saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include a path in front of the file name, it will be saved in that location.  For good organization, I recommend making a separate directory for your PDF files within your MEDIA_ROOT (as specified in your settings.py).  For example:

```
p = canvas.Canvas(MEDIA_ROOT + 'pdf/file_name.pdf')
```

Or, better yet, in your settings.py, define a new constant for your PDF location:

```
PDF_ROOT = MEDIA_ROOT + 'pdf/'
```

And then use it everywhere:

```
p = canvas.Canvas(PDF_ROOT + 'file_name.pdf')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked for me, this is the more fundamental approach towards my problem. Happy :)

Answer (score 0):

When you create the canvas, specify a filename with path:

```
p = canvas.Canvas(path + name)
```